# Openness In A Subspace Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Consider the set $Y=[-1,1]$ as a subspace in $\Bbb R$.

Let $E=\{x:0<|x|<1$ and $ \frac{1}{x}\notin\Bbb Z_+ \}$

Is $E$ open in $Y$?

My Try:

We can say $E$ is open in $Y$ if $\exists $ an open set $U$  in $\Bbb R$ such that $E=Y \cap U  $

So after some work I came up with the following choice for $U$,

$U=(-1,0)\cup (\cup _{z\in\Bbb Z_+}(\frac{1}{z+1},\frac{1}{z})) $

Hence, $E$ is open in $Y$

Did I get it right? Or is there an issue somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. In fact, you proved that $E$ is even open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, the openness in $\Bbb R $ follows!